# Android continuous Image capture after saving first image (Intent - ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Hi I am developing an app which requires to take pics which has to be sent over email. As the camera intent starts camera starts and it allows me to capture an image, when i press SAVE image is displayed in the image view.

Now i need to continue taking images, i.e., after pressing SAVE the camera should start again and be ready to capture pics till i click back button.

Could anyone please help?

For now my code is

```
        Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);          
        startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageURI(fileUri);
        } 

        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Just use startActivityForResult again i would say.

Comment: in the above code after capturing image when i click SAVE the image is displayed in imageview and the camera INTENT is closed. I need to continue capturing images and when i press back the images should be displayed in grid view.

Comment: Yes. Nothing simpler than that. As said: Just create a new intent and use startActivityForResult. What else? But displayng in a gridview does not make sense if you start the camera at the same time. Nobody would see the gridview then. Check resultCode to see which button is pressed.

Comment: Could you please help me with the code as am bit confused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the same intent again on activity result to start the camera again and handle it here only till when you want to capture the images.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageURI(fileUri);
            Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);          
            startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        } 

        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Devendra do u have any idea abt how to upload the images captured in a session to the grid view?

Comment: If i am not wrong than you are talking about the image capture session. In this case as you are capturing the multiple images than use collection as model for the gridview adapter to store these and use the same collection while populating these in grid views.

Comment: Kinda new to android so could you please help me out with some sample code if u have any

Comment: Naveed I don't have any sample code. This will be java collection eg Arraylist or something similar. Create collection of string type than add each fileUri you capture everytime from camera to this collection than use it.